# grails application shuts down as a result of caught exception in init

Tags: spring, exception, grails, groovy, application-shutdown

I have an grails 2.4.5 application that runs the init closure from bootstrap.groovy upon startup.  It may throw an exception or it may not, but in either case, the application *must* continue running.  What actually happens is during init() the app can't communicate with the server, a SocketTimeoutException is thrown by the underlying library and is then caught by my code.  The caught exception unexpectedly causes the application to invoke destroy() and the application shuts down which I don't want.  I expected that since the exception is caught, nothing wrong should be reported, and the application should remain running.

Here's the code using the RestTemplate library that causes the application to be destroyed.  Without this code it remains running.  The exception is caught and printed and then the app shuts down.

```
init = { servletContext ->
    try {
        // Send a post request
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", auth);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(10000);
        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory);
        ResponseEntity<String> rtString = rt.exchange(ME_URL + '/apps/register', HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // don't rethrow
        println e.getMessage(); // gets here, app is shutdown
    }
}
```

I assumed this has something to do with the library I used (RestTemplate) so I also tried using the Unirest library.  This also catches the exception but shuts down the application instead of continuing.

```
init = {
    try {
        res = Unirest
            .post(ME_URL + '/apps/register')
            .header('Authorization', auth)
            .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .body([clientId: CLIENT_ID])
            .asObject(Map.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // don't rethrow
        println e.getMessage(); // gets here, app is shutdown
    }
}
```

Now I began to think that maybe exceptions are leaking from init(), so I tried to manually throw an exception on purpose to test this theory.  I tried just a base Exception as well as the SocketTimeoutException that the previous two libraries threw.  This is interesting because I've proven that this exception doesn't somehow "leak" out of grails init closure.  This code below does NOT cause the application to shutdown and it remains running, which is what I want.

```
init = {
    try {
        throw new java.net.SocketTimeoutException("fake exception");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // don't rethrow
        println e.getMessage(); // gets here, but app continues
    }
}
```

Generally the only thing printed out in the error log is a stacktrace for a java.net.SocketTimeoutException, and my own instrumentation code to show that destroy() is indeed being called.

> 2017-01-09 12:01:51,825 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  -
>   Full Stack Trace: XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA.GatewayException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   XXX.YYY.ZZZ.registerApp(GatewayService.groovy:83)     at
>   XXX.YYY.ZZZ.initApp(GatewayService.groovy:50)     at
>   XXX.YYY.ZZZ.init(GatewayService.groovy:39)    at
>   XXX.YYY.ZZZ.slientInit(GatewayService.groovy:30)  at
>   XXX.YYY.ZZZ.BBB(Initializer.groovy:88)    at
>   BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:17)   at
>   grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:327)
>     at
>   grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:320)
>     at
>   grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:296)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
>     at
>   com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asObject(BaseRequest.java:80)
>     at XXX.YYY.ZZZ.registerApp(GatewayService.groovy:71)    ... 12 more

What I am looking for is:

1. Why this is happening
2. What I can do to fix this problem
3. If there's nothing I can do to fix my existing code, what is a workaround?  Workarounds that I've tried: using PostContext annotation and also afterPropertiesSet method after extending InitializingBean.  These two solutions do not work, as the init code I use will eventually use GORM, so GORM must be running at the time the code runs.  During these two hooks, GORM is not ready (Or so that error messages say).

I am using grails 2.4.5.

One more thing: I have eliminated all my code in init except for the code you see above, so I am fairly sure that these REST calls getting exceptions is directly responsible for the application shutting down.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have a couple of questions:
1) ME_URL, is this an independent server?
2) When you increase the timeout values to something far more generous, like maybe 30s does your server startup pause 30s and then fails to initialize?
3) Are you certain that the Exception that is thrown, is not in fact an Error (not a subclass of Exception, but still a Throwable)? Maybe replace catch(Execption e) with catch(Throwable e) ?

Comment: 1) ME_URL is currently set to http://localhost:8081/blahblahblah, and we encountered this issue.  Today, I discovered that the code suddenly worked - that is, we caught the exception and the app continues.  I tracked the problem down to a dev changing the port to something that isnt running on my computer so it still fails but with a HttpHostConnectException.  When using port 8081, it fails because there is a service running listening to that port, but the failure is SocketTimeoutException which somehow causes (directly or indirectly) the app to terminate despite the catch statement.

Comment: 2) Timeouts increased to 2 minutes and yes, the server startup pauses that amt of time.  It is a blocking call.  It then catches the exception (when using port 8081 - see #1) but the app is destroyed.  So it seems like timeout is not a factor

Comment: 3) Yes, sure it's an exception.  HttpHostConnectException and SocketTimeoutException.  I also tried catching Throwable for kicks, and behavior is the same. @loteq

Comment: Bounty is still available - need to find root cause and how I can change my code (without some crazy weird hack) to resolve my issue

Comment: what happens if you add a `finally` to your `try-catch`?  Can you get there?

Comment: It gets to the finally code and then continues to execute out of the init method. Ive stepped it out of init successfully.